# why does selenium code execute successsfully only in debug mode but fail in run mode?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-ide

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.27>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit      (
Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> webdriver.__version__
'3.0.2'
>>>
```

the selenium python testing code as the following:

```
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/")
self.assertEqual("Cubiender", driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_id("login_email").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("login_email").send_keys("gin@cubi.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_pwd").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("login_pwd").send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"submit\"]").click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Project List')
sleep(0.05)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='2588']").click()

sleep(0.05)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.menu > #inquireProject").click()
```

the above code can  run successfully in debug mode ,but  will be failed when running at 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='2588']").click()

even i added sleep

stacktrace:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" F:\python\sub_proj2.py true
```

Testing started at 10:53 ...

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\python\sub_proj2.py", line 41, in test_untitled
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.triangle").click()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 437, in find_element_by_css_selector
return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: span.triangle

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue, why is there a sleep before clicking on the element? and how is that input populated?

Comment: what is the exception thrown? stack trace?

Comment: Try to increase wait inside `sleep()` or use `explicit wait`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please share the stacktrace.

To me it seems,

- Either your `value='2588` is a dynamic one and changing with every instance load.
- May be the `sleep` halts the whole process. Why don't you use `wait`, an example mentioned below.

`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'someid')))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because in debug mode, it has more time to find the element. Try to increase sleep time or other solution to make sure the element is loaded.